# Right click on toggle button

Tags: javafx-2, togglebutton

I would like to run a stage by right mouse click on a toggle button,

```
ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton();
```

what OnMouse method should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for onPressed:

```
tb.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    if (mouseEvent.isSecondaryButtonDown()){
      System.out.println("hi");
    }
  }
});
```

for onReleased:

```
tb.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
      System.out.println("hi");
    }
  }
});
```